# Where does the pam_systemd.so line come from in system-auth and password-auth?

Tags: rhel, systemd, pam, logind

After converting a server to use SSSD for authentication the following line in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` caused very long (10-20 second) hangs when SSHing into the server:

`-session     optional      pam_systemd.so`

Removing this line fixed the hang, but of course whenever `authconfig --update --enablesssd` is run it regenerates those files, with that line.

How can I prevent this line from being generated? And what is causing it to be generated? It still was there after removing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and rerunnning `authconfig`...

It also seems that the man pages for `system-auth`, `password-auth`, `pam_systemd` don't have any useful info, but perhaps that's just me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant manual page can be invoked with `man authconfig`.

In EL variants, the configuration file is `/etc/sysconfig/authconfig`, but the documentation does not specify any setting for `systemd`. On CentOS7/RHEL7, `authconfig` is a symbolic link to the file,  `/usr/share/authconfig/authconfig.py`.

```
command -v authconfig
ls -l /usr/bin/authconfig
```

Within `/usr/share/authconfig`, the file, `authinfo.py` contains references to `systemd`.

```
cd /usr/share/authconfig
grep systemd *
```

Within this file, there are many arrays defining "stacks." In particular, there is an array specified for sessions. One might change the value from *True* to *False* and afterward test if the change caused the desired effect; but, I think this file probably gets overwritten on update.

```
[True, SESSION, LOGIC_OPTIONAL, "systemd", []]
```

One could script the removal of the configuration line instead of calling `authconfig` directly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# 
# File: /usr/local/sbin/enable_sssd.sh
#
authconfig --update --enablesssd
sed -ie "/-session[[:space:]]\+optional[[:space:]]\+pam_systemd.so/d" /etc/pam.d/system-auth
sed -ie "/-session[[:space:]]\+optional[[:space:]]\+pam_systemd.so/d" /etc/pam.d/password-auth
```

The PAM session software creates and destroys the login session. So, PAM session handler does things like modifying `utmp`, setting up an environment, storing Kerberos tickets, et al.  But, you should also have `session sufficient pam_sss.so` to handle sessions.